# Underline two letters separately

Tags: html

Is there a way to have non-continuous underline? I want the underline stop and restart (and see that visually) where I closed and reopened the  tags..

```html
W. Raven, “al-Wa<u>sh</u><u>sh</u>aʾ”
```

Comment: Yes it should work fine and it is valid markup, facing any problem?

Comment: *underline stop and restart* it works like that only, If you want visually give a space in between `u` tag

Answer (score 3):

The simplest option would be to style the underlines to have a small amount of padding on their right.

```css
u { padding-right: 2px; }
```

```html
W. Raven, “al-Wa<u>sh</u><u>sh</u>aʾ”
```

Alternatively, if you want to be smarter with it and only apply it to two consecutive underlines. This finds any underline that directly follows another, and adds padding to it's left.

```css
u + u{ 
  padding-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
W. Raven, “al-Wa<u>sh</u><u>sh</u>aʾ”
```

Comment: Thank you! I like this solution, but even after I changed the padding to 1px there is still a visible gap between the letters..

Comment: @alihaydar Yep, unfortunately this solution relies on the gap between the letters to separate the underline. I would probably go with frnt's solution ( 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47303896/1650337 ) as it doesn't rely on the letter gap. I've modified their solution in a way I prefer so you can just swap out your `u` elements with `span` (I'm not going to post it as an answer as it's 99% not my work) https://jsfiddle.net/avjd8oyn/

Comment: What should I do if there are other span tags on the page that should not have underlines?

Comment: @alihaydar Just add a class to the spans which are used as underlines, and apply the CSS to that. Updated fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/avjd8oyn/1/

Comment: Thank you very much! is there a way to have this lines to match regular <u> tags underline.. <u> tag underline is stay closer to the letter than this line..

Comment: @alihaydar Just change the `bottom` css property to maybe `1px` or `2px`, that should move the line up (This will vary based on your line height and font size)

Answer (score 3):

What if you could wrap that using `span tag` and then use `pseudo selector` to add spacing between `borders` below and not `between characters` as below,

```css
span{
  position:relative;
}
span:before{
  content:"";
  width:40%;
  height:1px;
  background:black;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
}
span:after{
  content:"";
  width:40%;
  height:1px;
  background:black;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
W. Raven, “al-Wa<span>shsh</span>aʾ”
```

Comment: Nice solution, it might be more flexible if one span was used per underline though. That way it's reusable even if it's not an even split of letters in each underline.

Comment: @DBS Yeah this way it won't break the word and if there are multiple span it can include class.

Comment: This is very nice, but they are not technically 'underline' now, right? If I needed this for one word I would use your solution, but there are thousands of already underlined words/letters in my case, and I only need to separate the underlines on some of them..

Comment: @alihaydar As you added that there are some of them, then you could use class and add same styling multiple times as in this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kt52pctk/

Answer (score 1):

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration:underline;
  padding-left:2px;
  }
```

```html
W. Raven, “al-Wa<span class="underline">sh</span><span class="underline">sh</span>aʾ”
```